# Storing composer packages under development in the vendor directory, how to set up autoloader?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

I am developing a package and I want to store it in the vendor directory before I publish it.

So, The path to say Basset's service provider once it is installed via composer is
`/siteroot/vendor/jasonlewis/basset/src/Basset/BassetServiceProvider.php`

which composer maps in it's autoloader fine, now If mine is at 
`/siteroot/vendor/hailwood/databaseconfigloader/src/DatabaseConfigLoader/DatabaseConfigLoaderServiceProvider.php`

What do I need to add to the composer.json file to make it generate the autoload mapping correctly?

I can manually edit the autoload_namespaces.php file to add the mapping 
`'Hailwood\\DatabaseConfigLoader' => $vendorDir . '/hailwood/databaseconfigloader/src/'`
and that works, but obviously gets overwritten when I do a composer update,  I tried adding

```
"psr-0": {
            "Hailwood\\DatabaseConfigLoader": "src/"
         }
```

to the `composer.json` but that outputs `'Hailwood\\DatabaseConfigLoader' => $baseDir . '/src/',` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In state, you don't respect PSR-0. So you have two solutions :

#### Respect PSR-0

You must put your code in `/siteroot/vendor/hailwood/databaseconfigloader/src/Hailwood/DatabaseConfigLoader/DatabaseConfigLoaderServiceProvider.php`. After that, simply do :

```
"psr-0":
{
    "Hailwood\\DatabaseConfigLoader": "vendor/hailwood/databaseconfigloader/src/"
}
```

#### Use *classmap* autoloading

Just try :

```
"classmap": ["vendor/hailwood/databaseconfigloader/src/"]
```